# React Hook Form with AntD Styling

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, antd, react-hook-form

I'm trying to figure out how to use react-hook-form with antd front end.

I have made this form and it seems to be working (it's part 1 of a multipart form wizard) except that the error messages do not display.

Can anyone see what I've done wrong in merging these two form systems?

I'm not getting any errors, but I think I have asked for both form fields to be required but if I press submit without completing them the error messages are not displayed.

```
import React from "react";
import useForm from "react-hook-form";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import { StateMachineProvider, createStore } from "little-state-machine";
import { withRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import { useStateMachine } from "little-state-machine";

import updateAction from "./updateAction";
import { Button, Form, Input,  Divider, Layout, Typography, Skeleton, Switch, Card, Icon, Avatar } from 'antd';


const { Content } = Layout 
const { Text, Paragraph } = Typography;
const { Meta } = Card;

createStore({
  data: {}
});

const General = props => {
  const { register, handleSubmit, errors } = useForm();
  const { action } = useStateMachine(updateAction);
  const onSubit = data => {
    action(data);
    props.history.push("./ProposalMethod");
  };


  return (

      <div>

        <Content
          style={{
            background: '#fff',
            padding: 24,
            margin: "auto",
            minHeight: 280,
            width: '70%'
          }}
        >
        <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubit)}>

          <h2>Part 1: General</h2>
            <Form.Item label="Title" >
              <Input 
                name="title" 
                placeholder="Add a title" 
                ref={register({ required: true })} 
              />
              {errors.title && 'A title is required.'}
            </Form.Item>
            <Form.Item label="Subtitle" >
              <Input 
                name="subtitle" 
                placeholder="Add a subtitle" 
                ref={register({ required: true })} 
              />
              {errors.subtitle && 'A subtitle is required.'}
            </Form.Item>
            <Form.Item>
              <Button type="secondary" htmlType="submit">
                Next
              </Button>
            </Form.Item>

        </Form>

        </Content>
      </div>  
  );
};

export default withRouter(General);
```

Comment: Why would you use 3rd party validator when you got built-in `getFieldDecorator`, also, you assuming that such hook that works on `html` components will work on custom components like `Form`, `Input` and so on.

Comment: What do you mean? I was trying to use the styling from antd with hooks. I couldn't figure it out so I gave up and am now using regular css with the hook form.

Comment: I didn't understand how styling with hooks related to what you asked

Comment: I think you were asking me why i was trying to use antd. That's why - the styling is consistent with the rest of the app. FYI: it doesn't work because antd doesn't have support for uncontrolled components

Comment: I didn't ask why you using antd, I asked why you use `react-hook-form`, and `antd` has support for uncontrolled components as I mentioned in the first comment.

Comment: I don't understand your first comment. getFieldDecorator is in antd. It doesn't work with react-hook-form. I'm not sure what is preventing us from understanding each other. Thanks anyway for trying to help

Answer (score 10, accepted):

react-hook-form author here. Antd Input component doesn't really expose inner `ref`, so you will have to `register` during `useEffect`, and update value during onChange, eg:

```
const { register, setValue } = useForm();

useEffect(() => {
  register({ name: 'yourField' }, { required: true });
}, [])

<Input name="yourField" onChange={(e) => setValue('yourField', e.target.value)}
```

i have built a wrapper component to make antd component integration easier: https://github.com/react-hook-form/react-hook-form-input

```
import React from 'react';
import useForm from 'react-hook-form';
import { RHFInput } from 'react-hook-form-input';
import Select from 'react-select';

const options = [
  { value: 'chocolate', label: 'Chocolate' },
  { value: 'strawberry', label: 'Strawberry' },
  { value: 'vanilla', label: 'Vanilla' },
];

function App() {
  const { handleSubmit, register, setValue, reset } = useForm();

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(data => console.log(data))}>
      <RHFInput
        as={<Select options={options} />}
        rules={{ required: true }}
        name="reactSelect"
        register={register}
        setValue={setValue}
      />
      <button
        type="button"
        onClick={() => {
          reset({
            reactSelect: '',
          });
        }}
      >
        Reset Form
      </button>
      <button>submit</button>
    </form>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks Bruce. Not sure I follow this. Error messages from antd work on the first step of a multistep form, but not subsequent steps. I'll keep trying and update this page if I figure something out.

Comment: Do you want to post this issue at our spectrum channel? I am happy to assist there.

Comment: if you want to trigger validation, setValue('xxx', value, true) it's all been documented on the website

Comment: Thanks @Bruce - I'll try again.

Comment: Thank you, it works! This ugly workaround, because of antd. I definitely wont use ant next time.

Comment: This is now built into RHF, so you should use a [Controller](https://react-hook-form.com/api/#Controller) component to wrap it instead.

Answer (score 3):

This is my working approach:

```
const Example = () => {

 const { control, handleSubmit, errors } = useForm()

  const onSubmit = data => console.log(data)
  console.log(errors)

  return (
    <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
      <Controller
        name="email"
        control={control}
        rules={{ required: "Please enter your email address" }}
        as={
          <Form.Item
            label="name"
            validateStatus={errors.email && "error"}
            help={errors.email && errors.email.message}
          >
            <Input />
          </Form.Item>
        }
      />
      <Button htmlType="submit">Submit</Button>
    </Form>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 2):

On writing such code:

```
<Input
  name="subtitle"
  placeholder="Add a subtitle"
  ref={register({ required: true })}
/>
```

You assume that `Input` reference is bound to `input`, but that's not true.

In fact, you need to bind it to `inputRef.input`.

You can check it with the next code:

```
const App = () => {
  const inputRef = useRef();
  const inputRefHtml = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(inputRef.current);
    console.log(inputRefHtml.current);
  });

  return (
    <FlexBox>
      <Input ref={inputRef} />
      <input ref={inputRefHtml} />
    </FlexBox>
  );
};
```

```sh
# Logs
Input {props: Object, context: Object, refs: Object, updater: Object, saveClearableInput: function ()…}

<input></input>
```

[image: Edit Q-58703615-3rdPartyInAnt]

> Note that `antd` is a complete UI library (using 3rd party "helpers" should "turn a red light"), in particular, `Form` has a validator implemented, you can see [a variety of examples in docs](https://ant.design/components/form/).

Answer (score 1):

In Ant Design v4.x + react-hook-form v6.x. We can implement as normally

```
import { useForm, Controller, SubmitHandler } from 'react-hook-form';
import * as yup from 'yup';
import { yupResolver } from '@hookform/resolvers/yup';

import { useIntl } from 'react-intl';
import { Input, Button, Form } from 'antd';

const SignInSchema = yup.object().shape({
  email: yup.string().email().required(),
  password: yup.string().required('required').min(6, 'passwordMin'),
});

interface PropTypes {
  defaultValues?: {
    email: string;
    password: string;
  };
  handleFormSubmit: SubmitHandler<{ email: string; password: string }>;
}

function SignInForm({ defaultValues, handleFormSubmit }: PropTypes) {
  const intl = useIntl();
  const { handleSubmit, control, errors } = useForm({
    defaultValues,
    resolver: yupResolver(SignInSchema),
  });

  return (
    <Form onFinish={handleSubmit(handleFormSubmit)}>
      <Form.Item
        validateStatus={errors && errors['email'] ? 'error' : ''}
        help={errors.email?.message}
      >
        <Controller
          as={Input}
          name="email"
          autoComplete="email"
          control={control}
          placeholder={intl.formatMessage({ id: 'AUTH_INPUT_EMAIL' })}
        />
      </Form.Item>
      <Form.Item
        validateStatus={errors && errors['password'] ? 'error' : ''}
        help={errors.password?.message}
      >
        <Controller
          as={Input}
          name="password"
          type="password"
          control={control}
          autoComplete="new-password"
          defaultValue=""
          placeholder={intl.formatMessage({ id: 'AUTH_INPUT_PASSWORD' })}
        />
      </Form.Item>

      <Button type="primary" htmlType="submit">
        {intl.formatMessage({ id: 'SIGN_IN_SUBMIT_BUTTON' })}
      </Button>
    </Form>
  );
}

export default SignInForm;
```

Comment: Hi, when adding the validateStatus & help props in Form.Item, I got the error index.js:1 Warning: findDOMNode is deprecated in StrictMode. findDOMNode was passed an instance of DomWrapper which is inside StrictMode. Instead, add a ref directly to the element you want to reference. Learn more about using refs safely here: https://reactjs.org/link/strict-mode-find-node. Please let me know how to fix it. Many thanks!

Comment: @ĐặngKiên this is an issue of the Antd Design, they might need to do a big changes for fixing this in the next version https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/issues/27921

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone is still interested in getting close to the default styles of the Form Inputs provided by Ant, here's how I got it to work:

```
import { Form, Button, Input } from 'antd';
import { useForm, Controller } from 'react-hook-form';

function MyForm() {
    const { control, handleSubmit, errors, setValue } = useForm();
    const emailError = errors.email && 'Enter your email address';

    const onSubmit = data => { console.log(data) };

    const EmailInput = (
        <Form.Item>
            <Input
                type="email"
                placeholder="Email"
                onChange={e => setValue('email', e.target.value, true)}
                onBlur={e => setValue('email', e.target.value, true)}
            />
        </Form.Item>
    );


    return (
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
            <Controller 
                as={EmailInput} 
                name="email" 
                control={control} 
                defaultValue=""
                rules={{
                    required: true
                }}
                validateStatus={emailError ? 'error' : ''}
                help={emailError}
            />

            <Button block type="primary" htmlType="submit">
                Submit
            </Button>
        </form>
    );
}
```

[Codesandbox sample](https://codesandbox.io/s/lucid-euler-yklq1)

Comment: Thanks for sharing - I'll have a look at this tonight. I'm still struggling to figure this out.